# Chemistry Riddle

Tags: chemistry

**Here is a riddle for all you science nerds out there! Each clue will give you a word or chemical. Tell me how these link together.**


**Clue 1: Work out the chemical and take its atomic symbol**

part 1: strong metal, to do with wolves
part 2: electrons are equal to sqrt(7225)
part 3: named in the same way as ytterbium and yttrium, found by Mosander


**Clue 2: Figure out what you get from the instructions**
Take pure hydrogen gas and pump it through oxygen gas. Then, mix this with sulfur dioxde. (H<sub>2</sub> + O<sub>2</sub> -> ? + SO<sub>2</sub> -> ?)


**Clue 3: Tell me what these physics terms are measured in**
part 1: Energy
part 2: Resistance
part 3: Take the last letter of part 2 and split it in half
part 4: Y

Comment: $H_2O + SO_2 \to H_2SO_3$, sulfurous acid, which makes the final rhyme fail.  You need to oxidize the $SO_2$ to $SO_3$ first, which is done using a vanadium catalyst.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid#Contact_process)

Comment: The rhyme is Johnny was a chemist's son but Johnny is no more for what he thought was H2) was H2SO4

Comment: Yes, I know it from decades ago.  Unfortunately in step 2 it appears you will not get $H_2SO_4$.  You need sulfur trioxide to do $H_2O+SO_3\to H_2SO_4$

Comment: OK. Well it's just a riddle and further knowledge is accepted

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Clue 1:
>  1) Tungsteen, aka Wolfram W
>  2) sqrt(7225) -> Astatine At
>  3) Erbium -> Er
>  Clue 1 = Water (H2O)
>  Clue 2 = H2SO4 (sulfuric acid)
>  Clue 3:
>  1) Energy -> Joule (J)
>  2) Resistence -> Ohm  (Ω)
>  3) Last letter of Ohm is m (thanks @hexomino) which split in half gives us n & n
>  4) Y
>  Clue 3 = Johnny
>  Solution (thanks to @Bananekopp))
>  Johnny Was A Chemist’s Son
>  but Johnny is no more.
>   What Johnny thought was H2O was H2SO4
>  I guess it has to be sung under the tune of "Old McDonald had a farm"
>  Explanation: Johnny drank "a glass of water" but he drank sulfuric acid

Comment: Clue 3: rot13(qvivqvat z tvirf hf gjb a, fb jr unir W Bu aa L... whfg tbbtyr "wbuaal jnf n purzvfgf fba")

Answer (score 6):

It's apparently not the intended answer, and you could argue it would need a language tag if it was, but still:

Clue 1: Work out the chemical and take its atomic symbol 
 part 1: strong metal, to do with wolves
 part 2: electrons are equal to sqrt(7225)
 part 3: named in the same way as ytterbium and yttrium, found by Mosander

> 1. Wolfram (W).
>  2. The number of electrons in an elemental atom is normally equal to that of protons, so it's astatine (At).
>  3. It could be terbium (Tb) or erbium (Er), but only the latter allows the answer to be a substance.
>  Clue 1: Water

Clue 2: Figure out what you get from the instructions
 Take pure hydrogen gas and pump it through oxygen gas. Then, mix this with sulfur dioxde. (H2 + O2 -> ? + SO2 -> ?)

> H2SO4

Clue 3: Tell me what these physics terms are measured in
 part 1: Energy
 part 2: Resistance
 part 3: Take the last letter of part 2 and split it in half
 part 4: Y

> 1. Energy: Joule (J) 
>  2. Resistance: Ohm (Ω, or sort of O)
>  3. The letter m becomes n. 
>  Jony means ions in Polish.

Solution:

> Like other acids, sulphuric acid also releases ions when dissolved in water.